Improving the proof of transitivity theorem
After a lot of work done in this answer by Andrej Bauer I decided to use his formal system to continue with theorems from Mendelsons book. Here is the next theorem after deduction(transitivity):

A -> B, B -> C ⊢ A -> C

Proof from the book:
1. A -> B  (hypothesis)
2. B -> C (hypothesis)
3. A      (hypothesis)
4. B      MP 1, 3   
5. C      MP 2, 4

Thus, A -> B, B -> C, A ⊢ C. So, by the deduction theorem, 
A -> B, B -> C ⊢ A -> C.

I formalized this theorem and Mendelsons proof with the following code:
Lemma transitivity1 Γ A B C : extend (extend Γ (A ~> B)) (B ~> C) |- A ~> C.
Proof.
  assert (H: extend (extend (extend Γ (A ~> B)) (B ~> C)) A |- C).
  (* C = MP B (B ~> C) *)
  - apply mp with (B := B).
    (* Prove the antecedent
       Γ, (A ~> B), (B ~> C), A |- B
       B = MP A (A ~> B)
    *)
    * apply mp with (B := A).
      + (* A is inside the set {Γ, (A ~> B), (B ~> C), A} *)
        apply hypo.
        unfold elem.
        unfold extend.
        right.
        reflexivity.
      + (* (A ~> B) is inside the set {Γ, (A ~> B), (B ~> C), A} *)
        apply hypo.
        unfold elem.
        unfold extend.
        left.
        unfold elem.
        auto.
    * (* (B ~> C) is inside the set {Γ, (A ~> B), (B ~> C), A} *)
      apply hypo.
      unfold elem.
      unfold extend.
      left.
      unfold elem.
      auto.
  - apply deduction in H.
    exact H.
Qed.

What I dislike in this proof: Mendelson can reference hypotheses with numbers, we have no names or numbers for them. And every time we use hypo constructor inside the proof we have to prove that the hypothesis in inside the set with a lot of manual work. Is it possible to attach names for the hypotheses or it would be better to use some automation (I tried auto, but it's too weak: it doesn't do beta reduction).
Any ideas for improvement of the proof for transitivity?

Can you make your title slightly more informative?

You can try firstorder to automate checking that a hypothesis is in the context.

For reference I placed the code that the OP is referring to in this gist. Please note that I made some changes relative to the code I posted in the other answer: made the first two arguments of hypo implicit, changed precedence level of ∈, and introduced a notation for extend. Make sure to use the linked version.
One simplification worth making is that instead of extend (extend Γ (A ~> B)) (B ~> C) we can use a general Γ with assumptions H1 : (A ~> B) ∈ Γ and H1 : (B ~> C) ∈ Γ. We get a more general theorem, and gain the ability to refer to the assumptions as H1 and H2.
I give below several variants of OP's theorem, in the order of increasing coolness.
(* For a complete working example, see https://gist.github.com/andrejbauer/0522b62e85dc13b205e70b00e21e694d *)

(* We give several versions of deducing A ~> B, B ~> C |- A ~> C.

   It is easier and more general to show the statement:
   if (A ~> B) ∈ Γ and (B ~> C) ∈ Γ then Γ |- A ~> C.
*)

(* The first version is the most explicit one, but it requires us
   to use "or_intror" and "or_introl" with bare hands. *)
Theorem example1 Γ A B C (H1 : A ~> B ∈ Γ) (H2 : B ~> C ∈ Γ) :
  Γ |- A ~> C.
Proof.
  apply deduction.
  apply (mp B).
  - apply (mp A).
    * apply (hypo (or_intror eq_refl)).
    * apply (hypo (or_introl H1)).
  - apply (hypo (or_introl H2)).
Qed.

(* Same as above, but with tactics "left" and "right" instead of manual
   use of "or_introl" and "or_intror". *)
Theorem example2 Γ A B C (H1 : A ~> B ∈ Γ) (H2 : B ~> C ∈ Γ) :
  Γ |- A ~> C.
Proof.
  apply deduction.
  apply (mp B).
  - apply (mp A).
    * apply hypo. now right.
    * apply hypo. now left.
  - apply hypo. now left.
Qed.

(* Ideally we would like a tactic that can solve easy cases of "hypo",
   but the previous proof is not amenable to an easy such tactic because
   we directed Coq using "left" and "right". Here is another proof,
   where all cases of "hypo" are solved the same way. *)
Theorem example3 Γ A B C (H1 : A ~> B ∈ Γ) (H2 : B ~> C ∈ Γ) :
  Γ |- A ~> C.
Proof.
  apply deduction.
  apply (mp B).
  - apply (mp A).
    * apply hypo. unfold extend, elem. auto.
    * apply hypo. unfold extend, elem. auto.
  - apply hypo. unfold extend, elem. auto.
Qed.

(* Now we can define a tactic that does the above steps.
   Note the difference between the tactic "hypo" and the constructor "hypo"!
   If you type "hypo" in tactic mode, it will use the tactic defined below,
   but if you type "apply hypo" it will use the constructor hypo. *)
Ltac hypo := (apply hypo ; unfold extend, elem ; auto).

(* The final version. *)
Theorem example4 Γ A B C (H1 : A ~> B ∈ Γ) (H2 : B ~> C ∈ Γ) :
  Γ |- A ~> C.
Proof.
  apply deduction.
  apply (mp B).
  - apply (mp A) ; hypo.
  - hypo.
Qed.

We can inspect the proof so constructed with Print example4, which gives:
example4 =
fun (Γ : formula -> Prop) (A B C : formula) (H1 : A ~> B ∈ Γ) (H2 : B ~> C ∈ Γ) =>
deduction
  (mp B (mp A (hypo (or_intror eq_refl : A ∈ Γ,, A)) (hypo (or_introl H1 : A ~> B ∈ Γ,, A)))
     (hypo (or_introl H2 : B ~> C ∈ Γ,, A)))
     : forall (Γ : formula -> Prop) (A B C : formula), A ~> B ∈ Γ -> B ~> C ∈ Γ -> Γ |- A ~> C

It's the "same" proof as in the textbook.

About your hypo tactic: is it possible to create a tactic referencing the hypothesis by name? Say, instead of writing hypo wrote hypo_explicit H1 or hypo_explicit H2?

Sure, there can be a tactic like that, but it's going to be more complicated. Do you think the way it's done in example1 is acceptable?

"Do you think the way it's done in example1 is acceptable?" - ideally it should not hard-code or_intror or or_introl. Maybe, unfold everything with repeat (unfold extend, elem) ; auto but instead of auto try to apply the hypothesis to every element until it succeeds?

C ∈ extend (extend Γ A) B unfolds to (C ∈ Γ ∨ C = A) ∨ C = B. We can only apply the hypothesis the first disjunct, the other two are solved by eq_refl. What do you imagine would happen if we had H : C ∈ Γ and the context is extend (extend Γ A) C? There are two ways to solve it.

"C ∈ extend (extend Γ A) B unfolds to (C ∈ Γ ∨ C = A) ∨ C = B. We can only apply the hypothesis the first disjunct" - yes, but now I have theorems with many folded extends, and this rule won't work. Maybe, I should post them.

Yes, please do. Also, your code is not carved in stone, you can go back and change it :-)
